# Bash script: Syntax error in conditional expression

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm new around the neighborhood and stuck with a syntax error. Please take a look and maybe someone can assist. I'm trying to run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

main () {
 dpkg -query -s $1 &> /tmp/pkg_verify
 if grep -q 'not installed' /tmp/verify
 then
  echo -e "\e[31m$1 is not installed. installing..\e[0m"
  apt-get install $1
  echo -e "\e[31m$1 is not installed and ready to use\e[0m"
 else
  echo -e "\e[31m$1 is already installed\e[0m"
 fi
 rm -f /tmp/pkg_verify
 for test in $@; do main $test; shift; done
 echo -e "\e[31mDone\e[0m"
}
for test in $@; do main $test; shift; done

echo -e "\e[31mDone\e[0m"
```

But when I try to execute it I'm facing with endless loop:

```
grep: /tmp/verify: No such file or directory
16 is already installed
```

I truly tried to find the answer, tried to change the `if` to couple of different forms but with out any success. Does any one have an idea why that is? What should I change so that the script can run?

Thanks in advance to all the helpers.

Comment: BTW your "shift" is unneeded, as the for loop steps through the parameters in $@ anyway.

Comment: I think `/tmp/verify` should be `/tmp/pkg_verify` (i.e., you're using the wrong temporary file name).

Comment: thanks @chepner, but still after changing the file name the next error is apperd: ***dpkg: error: unknown option -q Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages []; Use dselect' or aptitude' for user-friendly package management; Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values; Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options; Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files; Options marked [] produce a lot of output - pipe it through less' or more' ! top is already installed Done*** any idae why is that?

Answer (score 3):

You have *two* `else` following each other. That can't work. It's either `elif condition` or just a single `else`.

The infinite loop is caused by `main` calling itself recursively.

And third, it's probably a bug to `shift` when iterating with `for i in "$@"`.

To debug a script (free of syntax errors) use `set -x` near the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
if [[ -z `grep 'not installed' /tmp/pkg_verify` ]]
```

with this if condition:

```
if grep -q 'not installed' /tmp/pkg_verify
```

#### Full Script:

```
main () {
     dpkg-query -s "$1" > /tmp/pkg_verify
     if grep -q 'not installed' /tmp/pkg_verify
     then
       echo -e "\e[31m$1 is not installed. installing..\e[0m"
       apt-get install "$1"
       echo -e "\e[31m$1 is not installed and ready to use\e[0m"
    else
       echo -e "\e[31m$1 is already installed\e[0m"
    fi
 }
 rm -f /tmp/pkg_verify
 for test in $@; do main "$test"; done
 echo -e "\e[31mDone\e[0m"
```

Comment: @nubhava thanks for the quick replay, as you said i changed the if condition and when im trying to run it i get:
line 21: syntax error near unexpected toke 'else'
line 21: 'else'
any idie? 
p.s can you please explain what was wrong in the if condition that i write?

Comment: Problem with your condition was that the output of `grep` has white-spaces in it and because of that if condition gets multiple arguments after `-z` where it expects only one argument. Why you are getting error elsewhere in the code is difficult to say until I see full script. Post your complete script in the question so that I check and suggest.

Comment: @nubhave: as your request i'm posting the script after changed the if condition, please check the question

Comment: Ah looks like you have 2 else blocks that is the problem now.

Comment: Also I posted your full script (fixed) in my answer.

Comment: thanks again for the help I really appreciate it! we have some process but still it not working, when i'm run it now I get an endless loop, I wrote exactly what you posted and I get:
**grep: /tmp/verify: No such file or directory
16 is already installed**
I'll paste the script as it is right now on the question please have a look something is still not right, any idea what it can be?

Comment: ok updated answer with your full script. Just copy/paste this into your shell and try it.

Comment: @user3107121 See my updated answer for why there's an infinite loop.

Comment: @user3107121 The grep error is due to a typo: `/tmp/verify` should be `/tmp/pkg_verify`.

Comment: Yes that's why I took out recursive calls in my last edited script and yes `/tmp/pkg_verify` is a valid point

Comment: @anubhava, I tried to run it like you post but now I getting different error, didn’t you was able to run it well? please check the below error:
dpkg: error: unknown option -q

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
top is already installed
Done

Comment: I work on OSX so can't really test all the Ubuntu specific dpkg commands. For the all the commands starting with dpkg you will need to check its man page.

Comment: Can you try edited code again. You had space between `dpkg` and `-query` but command is `dpkg-query`